# How to have user's passwords remembered in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, centos

How to I get linux to stop prompting me for a password and remember it? For instance, when using the root user, I always get prompted, but I would rather only be prompted once per user session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of the console (bash) there is no way to do that. You could put yourself in the "wheel group" and you would only have to type `sudo xyz` instead of `su [Enter] xyz` and it won't bug you every time. In terms of the GUI (I see you tagged Ubuntu) certain tasks (those found in the System -> Administration menu in GNOME) will remember the root credentials for a set time or until you log out, automatically.